# How I set " document showing markup" as default instead of " document" in word when exporting as pdf

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to change the pdf "publish what" default which is set as document to "document showing markup" as default.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that you want Track changes to be the default for new documents?

Comment: Could you please check the image that I attached. In export what section , default set in "document" and I want to change the default to " document with markup"  . Basically I want to set document with markup as default instead of document